# SQL Update: Append data to a cell

Tags: php, mysql, sql, append

I would like to create an SQL query which updates said columns with new data but also data from that particular row which is being update. If you could imagine, "prepending" new data to a cell but that keeps that same data in that cell. For example, I want to add the follow, `"some_text"`, to a cell which already has `"other_text"` to make: `"some_textothertext"`. However I want to set `"some_text"` to a variable in PHP.

I have no idea on how to approach or complete this and a word of guidance is very much appreciated, thank you. :3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the MySQL **[CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)** function is what you're looking for.

```
UPDATE
    some_table
SET
    some_text = CONCAT(some_text, '<<echo php variable here>>')
WHERE
    id = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following this steps:

1. Retrieve data from current wanted cell.
2. Append your data to the
3. retrieved cell in variable. Now, update your cell.